# error upon flushing an object with array of objects in association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

i'm receiving the following error message upon persisting and flushing an object with its associations:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
the type array, object given, called in  
.../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 519 and defined in 
.../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php line 48
```

what i have is a single table inheritance with this as the base object:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * ObjectData
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="object_data")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Edexp\CoreBundle\Entity\ObjectDataRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_name", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "request" = "Edexp\MessageBundle\Entity\RequestData"
 * })
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class ObjectData
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
private $created_at;

/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="data")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="`key`", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $key;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="data", type="blob")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set created_at
 *
 * @param \DateTime $createdAt
 * @return ObjectData
 */
public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
{
    $this->created_at = $createdAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get created_at
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->created_at;
}

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @return ObjectData
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get user
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}

/**
 * Set key
 *
 * @param string $key
 * @return ObjectData
 */
public function setKey($key)
{
    $this->key = $key;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get key
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getKey()
{
    return $this->key;
}

/**
 * Set data
 *
 * @param string $data
 * @return ObjectData
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get data
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function prepareForPersist()
{
    $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
}
}
```

and an additional object that inherits from ObjectData:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use MyProject\CoreBundle\Entity\ObjectData;

/**
* RequestData
*
* @ORM\Entity()
*/
class RequestData extends ObjectData
{
    /**
    * var Request $request
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Request", inversedBy="data")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $request;

    /**
    * Set request
    *
    * @param Request $request
    * @return RequestData
    */
    public function setRequest($request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
    * Get request
    *
    * @return Request
    */
    public function getRequest()
    {
        return $this->request;
    }
}
```

and here's the object that utilizes the RequestData entity:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Request
*
* @ORM\Table(name="requests")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RequestRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
*/
class Request
{
    /**
    * @var integer $id
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @var Message $message
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Message", inversedBy="requests")
    */
    private $message;

    /**
    * @var RequestType $type
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RequestType")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $type;

    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection $data
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(
    *       targetEntity="RequestData",
    *       mappedBy="request",
    *       cascade={"persist","remove"}
    * )
    */
    private $data;

    /**
    * @var datetime $created_at
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
    */
    private $created_at;

    /**
    * @var text $comment
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="comment", type="text")
    */
    private $comment;

    /**
    * @var ArrayCollection $responses
    *
    * @ORM\OneToMany(
    *       targetEntity="Response",
    *       mappedBy="request",
    *       cascade={"persist","remove"}
    * )
    */
    private $responses;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data      = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->responses = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    * Get id
    *
    * @return integer
    */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
    * Set message
    *
    * @param Message $message
    */
    public function setMessage($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
    * Get message
    *
    * @return Message
    */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    /**
    * Set type
    *
    * @param RequestType $type
    */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;
    }

    /**
    * Get type
    *
    * @return RequestType
    */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
    * Set created_at
    *
    * @param datetime $createdAt
    */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->created_at = $createdAt;
    }

    /**
    * Get created_at
    *
    * @return datetime
    */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->created_at;
    }

    /**
    * Set comment
    *
    * @param text $comment
    */
    public function setComment($comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    /**
    * Get comment
    *
    * @return text
    */
    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }

    /**
    * Add response
    *
    * @param Response $response
    */
    public function addResponse($response)
    {
        foreach ( $this->responses as $r ) {
            if ( $r->getUser() == $response->getUser() )
                return;
        }

        $this->responses->add($response);
    }

    /**
    * Get responses
    *
    * @return ArrayCollection
    */
    public function getResponses()
    {
        return $this->responses;
    }

    public function hasResponse($user)
    {
        foreach ( $this->responses as $r ) {
            if ( $r->getUser() == $user )
                return $r;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function addData($data)
    {
        $data->setRequest($this);
        $this->data->add($data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
    * @ORM\PrePersist
    */
    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->created_at = new \DateTime();
    }
}
```

and finally the code that results in an error:

```
            use MyProject\MessageBundle\Entity\Request as MyRequest;

    $data = new RequestData();
    $data->setUser($user);
    $data->setKey('user_id');
    $data->setData(6);

    $req = new MyRequest();
    $req->setMessage($message);
    $req->setComment('bla');
    $req->setType($doctrine->getRepository('MessageBundle:RequestType')->find(1));
    $req->addData($data);

    $em->persist($req);
    $em->flush();
```

any suggestions as to what might be wrong here?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here's what i had to do in order to make it work.

i had to change the association in ObjectData from:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="data")
```

to

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="data")
```

added the data field to the User entity accordingly.

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection $data
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ObjectData", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $data;
```

and voila, it worked.

Comment: Your answer had me take another look at my mappings again and again. It's just too easy to blame the framework, because the developer (of course) has "checked everything" and "everything is as it should be" and "makes no mistakes"... while all of that is false :P Just too stubborn to admit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$req->addData(array($data));
```

Explanation:

arrayCollection constructor type hints an array as its parameter, so you need to always pass it an array.

Comment: that didn't work. i had to fix the associations for it to work.